# Sqlcmd multiline script in terraform local provisioner

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-sql-database, sqlcmd

When I run this provisioner it gives me error:

```
exit status 2. Output: Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'User'..
│ /bin/sh: 2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

TF code:

```
resource "null_resource" "init" {
  
depends_on = [azurerm_mssql_firewall_rule.creator]

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
sqlcmd -S tcp:someserver.database.windows.net -d master -U ${var.mssql_admin_username} -P ${var.mssql_admin_password}
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = 'poweruser')
BEGIN
CREATE USER poweruser;
ALTER USER poweruser WITH PASSWORD '${var.mssql_admin_password}';
END;
QUIT
    EOT
  }
}
```

Looks like it takes it whole as one command. How can I split it into two commands? I cant take sql part to separate file since i need get `'${var.mssql_admin_password}'` value.

Answer (score 0):

In order for `sqlcmd` to work in `local exec` you need to have SSMS downloaded and installed in your Local machine, Once you install SSMS, The `sqlcmd` is installed by default. Refer below:-

**SSMS download [**reference**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver16):-**

Now, run the below terraform scripts to deploy Azure SQL DB and use local_exec to run sql command to create DB and and Table.

**`My locals.tf:-`**

```
locals {
  resource_group_name="silicon-app-grp"
  location="North Europe"  
}
```

**`My main.tf:-`**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.37.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  # Configuration options
  subscription_id = "sub-id"
  tenant_id       = "tenant-id"
  client_id       = "client-id"
  client_secret   = "client-secret"
  features {}
}
```

**`My sqldatabase.tf:-`**

```
resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "sqlserver" {
  name                         = "sqlserver400908"
  resource_group_name          = local.resource_group_name
  location                     = local.location
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = "adminuser"
  administrator_login_password = "Admin@123"  
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_resource_group.appgrp
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "appdb" {
  name           = "appdb"
  server_id      = azurerm_mssql_server.sqlserver.id
  collation      = "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
  license_type   = "LicenseIncluded"
  max_size_gb    = 2  
  sku_name       = "S0"  

 lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      license_type
    ]
  }
  
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_mssql_server.sqlserver
      ]
  
}


resource "azurerm_mssql_firewall_rule" "allowmyclient" {
  name             = "AllowClientIP"
  server_id        = azurerm_mssql_server.sqlserver.id
  start_ip_address = "103.133.65.143"
  end_ip_address   = "103.133.65.143"
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_mssql_server.sqlserver
  ]
}
```

***`My sqlcmd.tf:-`***

```
resource "null_resource" "database_setup" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
      command = "sqlcmd -S ${azurerm_mssql_server.sqlserver.fully_qualified_domain_name} -U ${azurerm_mssql_server.sqlserver.administrator_login} -P ${azurerm_mssql_server.sqlserver.administrator_login_password} -d appdb -i 01.sql"
  }
  depends_on=[
    azurerm_mssql_database.appdb
  ]
}
```

***01.sql*** **is my sql script file in the same folder as my terraform files above.**

**01.sql script:-**

```sql
CREATE TABLE Products
(
     ProductID int,
     ProductName varchar(1000),
     Quantity int
)


INSERT INTO Products(ProductID,ProductName,Quantity) VALUES (1,'Mobile',100)

INSERT INTO Products(ProductID,ProductName,Quantity) VALUES (2,'Laptop',200)

INSERT INTO Products(ProductID,ProductName,Quantity) VALUES (3,'Tabs',300)
```

[**Reference**](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/mssql_server)

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this chatgpt answer? Your answer doesn't solve the problems I describe in my question at all. Also you definitely doesnt need SSMS installed for sqlcmd to work...

Comment: No, I have tried this in my VS Code, Can you check my sqlcmd.tf ? I have added proper connection string for the sqlcmd to work? Also, Yes SSMS is not mandatory. But it is one of the ways to have sqlcmd installed in your system by default.

Comment: Login failed for user 'User'..
│ /bin/sh: 2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected > Check my sqlcmd in sqlcmd.tf file, And try to make your connection string in the same format. I have referenced the administrator username and password from sqldatabase.tf

Comment: I'd recommend you to try my code above, This should help you in running sqlcmd and you won't get ODBC errors for Login.

Comment: @Michael Try to add your IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = 'poweruser')
BEGIN
CREATE USER poweruser;
ALTER USER poweruser WITH PASSWORD '${var.mssql_admin_password}';
END;
QUIT sql command in 01.sql command file, and then run this provisioner "local-exec" {
      command = "sqlcmd -S ${azurerm_mssql_server.sqlserver.fully_qualified_domain_name} -U ${azurerm_mssql_server.sqlserver.administrator_login} -P ${azurerm_mssql_server.sqlserver.administrator_login_password} -d appdb -i 01.sql"
  } your command should work